# "bootmgr is missing" after connecting a second internal hdd to motherboard

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bootmgr

I have my internal hdd with win10 installed, that is connected to motherboard. but as soon as i connect a second one then my pc says bootmgr is missing, even though my pc is set to boot from the first hdd. What could be the problem then, and how to solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @guest: First, Try to use popup boot function and select the required drive manually and see what's happening. Second, check solution provided by Microsoft: ["Bootmgr is missing Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart" error when you start Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-bootmgr-is-missing-press-ctrl-alt-del-to-restart-error-when-you-start-windows-8bc1b94b-d243-1027-5410-aeb04d5cd5e2)

Comment: @guest BIOS or UEFI boot? If the latter then booting "drives" isn't applicable, please check UEFI settings > Boot menu. If the former (or Legacy/CSM boot in UEFI hardware) then yes, you need to select a drive to boot from and often when adding another the boot order changes, confirm and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Check to make sure the appropriate hdds are cabled correctly on the MB.
For example, the hd with win10 should be master.  The other hd should be slave.
Easiest way to check is to simply swap the two on the MB.

Comment: *hd with win10 should be master* Master/Slave isn't used since PATA drives, not applicable to SATA. Although not impossible it's highly unlikely to find Windows 10 installed in such old hardware. And in any case it's wrong because even with PATA drives and BIOS boot we could select any drive to boot from.